# Using jQuery click() handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have the following table in my Razor View, which goes through a ViewBag items using a foreach. As you can see, each button has its value `value="@item.Id"`. Let's say there are ten items in my ViewBags, and **id** starts from 1 to 10.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Name</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Operation</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Guests)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.LastName, @item.FirstName</td>
            <td>
               <button id="btn" value="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Click Now</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
```

I also have a click handler:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

After the code is executed, a table with 10 records along with a button will be displayed. I want to display an alert with the user ID on the browser when a button is clicked. However, the problem is, it only shows the first button value on the alert and does not show anything from the second button to the end.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe because there is only one button with #btn id ?

Comment: Ids are unique, you can't have 10 items with the same ids. Use classes instead.

Comment: I can't use a class because I already have a class for bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

css "id" and "class", "#" and "." retrospectively

id need to be unique, class can be shared.
as you want to target multiple buttons you do this with css class..

see small changes below.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Name</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Operation</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Guests)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.LastName, @item.FirstName</td>
            <td>
               <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="btn-@item.Id"  
                 value="@item.Id">Click Now</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('.btn').click(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```